# convert querystring to panel control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a bunch panels on a page. panel1, panle2 ..., I want to make a panel visible based on a querystring. Ived tried:

```
Dim s As String
s = Request.QueryString("s")
Dim p As Panel = CType(Me.Controls(s), Panel)
p.Visible = True
```

This doesn't work. Maybe there is a whole different way to go about it.
Thanks.

Comment: What is your query string? if s=PanelId then it should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're passing actual Panel ID (e.g. `http://mysite.com/page.aspx?s=panel1`), you should use 'FindControl' method:

```
Dim p As Panel = CType(Me.FindControl(s), Panel)
```